# Query is too complex/a way to better loop through folder of excel files

Tags: sql, vba, excel

```
Do While sFile <> ""

    strQuery = strQuery & _
     "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A15:E999] " & _
     "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sFile & "'" & _
     "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;ExtendedProperties='HDR=YES;'] " & _
     "UNION "

    sFile = Dir()

Loop

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.Open strConnection
Set objRecordSet = objConnection.Execute(strQuery)
```

Hi,

I have the above code which takes data from all files in a folder and writes into a separate file via ADODB data connection. The issue is, when files are 20+, the 'Query is too complex error' pops up as all queries to get 200 files are combined in 1 single query.

I want to know if there is a workaround in SQL side as my knowledge is basic. Things I am looking for are 2nd or multiple data connections which gathers up (say) 5 files per query that all write on the same 1 file?

If that's hard, is it possible to read files inside a folder in batches while keeping track of the files? (hence running the macro multiple times via a second loop using VBA?)

Thank you for your help or directions on doing this.

Comment: What are you doing with the results of the query?  Is there a reason that they all need to be unioned into one result set?

Comment: I am trying to combine all data in to one file in the fastest possible method hence the union

Comment: I'd think the main bottleneck would be the individual file accesses much more than the overhead to create the recordset. Have you benchmarked it with individual file reads?

Comment: I may be wrong in this but all the data is in "Sheet1$A15:E999" (some up to E500) of all files. Was this what you meant by benchmark?

Comment: No, by [benchmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_(computing)) I meant timing the execution time with and without the `UNION` to actually compare the performance of the two methods.

Comment: Without union, wouldn't it give an error (in fact it did) as it tries to combines all the data in all files (sorry if my questions are amateur)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126272/discussion-between-dingo-and-comintern).